# Use custom SpotBugs plugin in multi-module maven project

Tags: java, maven, spotbugs

I have create a custom SpotBugs plugin for maven like described [here](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/implement-plugin.html#create-maven-project) in a multi-module maven project. But I cannot figure out how to use it. There really is not much documentation or examples for this.

Like described [here](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html) I have used `pluginList` and `plugins` configuration properties for SpotBugs. But it does not report the bug when I run `spotbugs:spotbugs`. Other bugs are reported. Any idea what the problem might be?

I am using Spotbugs in maven like this:

```
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spotbugs.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pluginList>custom-spotbugs.jar</pluginList>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>custom-spotbugs</artifactId>
                            <version>${custom.build.version}</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Edit: I noticed that I had to run `mvn site` for the reporting plugins to work. But the next problem is that the configuration values cannot be changed. I had `<effort>Max</effort>` in the configuration and even if I remove it, it is still used. Are the configuration cached or something?

Comment: What about https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html

Comment: I also have a build-tools module for sharing a FindbugsExclude xml file. But I don't know if it helps. I tried putting the jar file from pluginList in the resource folder but it still does not work.